# 1GB on my PC not enough

Tags: windows-7

I'm using my PC only for Ebay, itunes, emailing and surfing the net.  I do not understand why my computer is already showing that the memory is full when there is 1GB of memory.

Can someone advise as I'm not sure what to do at all.  It's 1GB with 64 bit whatever that is. Have synced my iphone with the pc and uploaded about 700 photos to the pc and about 20 CDs as well.

Any suggestions please before it crashes completely.

Comment: 1 GB is the amount of memory, not disk space. Your 700 photos and 20 CD are on the hard disk and do not use memory. So you can ignore that part. As for the rest, how much is actually in use and how much are buffers. How many programs do you run at the same time? Also, why would it crash? When the memory is full it just starts to swap, which will make it slower. Which is annoying, but far different from a crash.

Comment: Gosh thanks guys BUT I looked at the size in the computer window. It says: Local Disc C: 1.3GM free of 37.1GB. Isn't the C drive the hard disk? What are buffers and when you ask how many programs do I run at the same time do you mean how many programs have I got open? ie email, ebay, google? Really appreciate your responses hugely. Friends have advised that I should save photos onto a USB stick but what's the point of having the pc?????

Comment: Open/active programs use memory. Pictures, music and other documents of harddisk space. It seems that you are almost out of harddisk space (Is that 1.3GM free a '1.3MB free' or a '1.3GB free' ?).  Either way,a 37 GB drive is rather small and there is a limit to how much you can store on it. Either get external storage, or a bigger drive, or store less on the harddisk. That can be less content, or smaller content. (E.g. mp3s of the CDs rather than flacs).

Answer (score 3):

You have 1 GB of RAM. It's a type of memory that's used for temporary data storage by Windows and programs.

1 GB is not very much (modern PCs have 4-32 GB), so your PC will suffer from low performance (I guess you have Windows 7, 8 or Vista). But as long as you're ok with that, it doesn't matter.

The message you see isn't about RAM, but about your hard drive - the place where data is stored for longer periods of time (for example these CDs and synced data).

Every CD is about 700 MB (0,7 GB), so I estimate you have used about 20 GB of drive space. That's not a huge amount, but I don't know how big is your hard drive and what's already been there. You can see used and free space amounts in the *Computer* window.

Delete some of your files and the message will be gone.

Comment: Gosh thanks guys BUT I looked at the size in the computer window.  It says: Local Disc C: 1.3GM free of 37.1GB.  Isn't the C drive the hard disk? What are buffers and when you ask how many programs do I run at the same time do you mean how many programs have I got open? ie email, ebay, google?  Really appreciate your responses hugely.  Friends have advised that I should save photos onto a USB stick but what's the point of having the pc?????

Comment: @salhonestgal 40 GB is a very small disk and 1.3 GB isn't very much too - you should have at least 10 GB of free space left "just in case". Someone who set up your PC did an awful job creating such a small disk. But, you should also see other disks - C: shouldn't be the only one (such small hard disks aren't even manufactured since like 12 years). If you have any other drives, you can keep your data on these.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [system requirements for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/systemrequirements) call for a *minimum* of 2 GB of RAM for a PC with a 64-bit processor, so I would recommend that you add at least another gigabyte of RAM.

A 40 GB hard drive (your 'C' drive) isn't very large if you want to store music and large numbers of photos. In the short-term, you should move at least some of the photos to another storage system such as a USB drive or CD-ROM. Longer term, depending on your computer's hardware, you might be able to add a second hard drive (a 'D' drive) without too much trouble. You could store your photos on the D drive, leaving more space free on the C drive.

Answer (score -1):

Slowing down of the PC is almost always a sign of spywares. Use Spybot Search and Destroy and Malwarebytes Antimalware to clean your PC, preferably in Safe Mode. Also run MSCONFIC and uncheck any services and startup programs you don't need when loading Windows (eg Skype etc can be loaded later at will). This should get your PC fast again. Last thing, check the add-ons in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. If your first page has changed to conduit or similar "search engine", then not only you have spywares but unless you remove all this stuff from Internet Explorer and Mozilla they will reinstall at first launch of the browser! I'm not going to give full details of how to do it as I have already done in an older post.

Comment: Spyware can slow things down, but the OP never said that the PC was slowing down. The only 'detail' given was that memory was full along with a confusing mix or memory (RAM) details and storage (HDD place).